# How to create a gz-compatible file with zlib?

Tags: c++, c, zlib, gzip

I want to use the *zlib* to produce a *gz-compatible* output file with C++.

I installed the developer package for [zlib](http://zlib.net/), which can be used -- as I understand it -- to create gz-compatible files both on Unix and on Windows.

```
sudo aptitude install libz-dev
```

Although I write a C++-program, I quite I followed the [usage example](http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html) in the relevant points, I think. I also compiled the example to `zpipe.c` unchanged.

Alas, what I get is *not* a gz-compatible output.

```
$ ./zpipe.x < data.txt > x.gz
$ file x.gz
x.gz: data
$ gunzip x.gz 
gzip: x.gz: not in gzip format
```

I thought that the reason here might be, because `deflateSetHeader` is not called. So I added that into my own source code, i.e. (excerpt, you can find the [full code here](http://codepad.org/lKVPPXAx)):

```
struct DeflateWrap { // RAII wrapper
  z_stream strm_ ; // C-Struct from zlib.h
  explicit DeflateWrap() : strm_{} {
    strm_.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    strm_.zfree = Z_NULL;
    strm_.opaque = Z_NULL;
    auto ret = deflateInit2(&strm_, LEVEL,
                 Z_DEFLATED, 15, 9, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY); 
    if(ret != Z_OK) throw std::runtime_error("Error ZLib-Init");
  }
  // ...more, eg. operator-> and *...
};

void pack(const string& infn) {
  DeflateWrap dwrap {};
  //...
  dwrap->avail_in = indata.size();
  dwrap->next_in = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(indata.data());
  gz_header header {0}; // <<< HEADER HERE
  header.name = const_cast<unsigned char*>(
    reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(infn.c_str()));
  header.comment = Z_NULL;
  header.extra = Z_NULL;
  bool first = true;
  do {
    dwrap->avail_out = outdata.size();
    dwrap->next_out = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(outdata.data());
    if(first) {
      cerr << deflateSetHeader(&(dwrap.strm_), &header); // <<< SET HDR HERE
      first = false;
    }
    deflate(&(dwrap.strm_), Z_FINISH); // zlib.h: this packs
    auto toWrite = outdata.size() - dwrap->avail_out;
    outf.write(outdata.data(), toWrite);
  } while (dwrap->avail_out == 0);
}
```

To my interpretation I followed the [manual](http://zlib.net/manual.html) for `deflateSetHeader`:

- I even used `deflateInit2` instead of `deflateInit`, probably unnecessarily
- the call of `deflateSetHeader` is immediatly after `deflateInit2`
- the call of `deflateSetHeader` is before any call of `deflate`

...and still I get a `-2`, i.e. `Z_STREAM_ERROR` from the `deflateSetHeader` call. Although, the output I produce can be uncompressed with `zpipe.c`, therefore it can't be totally wrong, can it?

Any idea how to set a gz-compatible header?

**Update:**

As I see it I use the C++-pendant to

```
SET_BINARY_MODE(stdin);
SET_BINARY_MODE(stdout);
```

by opening the files like this:

```
ifstream inf{ infn, ifstream::binary };
ofstream outf { infn + ".gz", ofstream::binary };
```

Also, I wonder why the `zpipe.c` example I produced also does not make a gunzip-compatible file, as I described before. From what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12117919/472245) it should.

Comment: NOT a duplicate of [Using zlib to create a gzip file using zpipe.c example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115829/using-zlib-to-create-a-gzip-file-using-zpipe-c-example), because I use *binary mode* in my C++ code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

windowBits can also be –8..–15 for raw deflate. In this case, -windowBits determines the window size. deflate() will then generate raw deflate data with no zlib header or trailer, and will not compute an adler32 check value.

windowBits can also be greater than 15 for optional gzip encoding. Add 16 to windowBits to write a simple gzip header and trailer around the compressed data instead of a zlib wrapper. The gzip header will have no file name, no extra data, no comment, no modification time (set to zero), no header crc, and the operating system will be set to 255 (unknown). If a gzip stream is being written, strm->adler is a crc32 instead of an adler32.

Comment: To be clear, this is the important comment from the deflateInit2() function in zlib, particularly, the part about adding 16 to windowBits for the gzip header.

Answer (score 3):

Although I read the documentation of `deflateSetHeader` that the output file *is* gz-compatible, a bit further down there is a hint that it may be not so.

> This library supports reading and writing files in gzip (.gz) format with an interface similar to that of stdio, using the functions that start with "gz". The gzip format is different from the zlib format. gzip is a gzip wrapper, documented in RFC 1952, wrapped around a deflate stream.

Thus, when I use the different set of functions `gz...` I get gz-compatible output *and* simpler code:

```
struct GzWrite { // RAII-Wrapper
    gzFile gz_ ; // C-Struct aus zlib.h
    explicit GzWrite(const string& filename)
        : gz_{gzopen(filename.c_str(),"wb9")}
    {
        if(gz_==NULL) throw std::runtime_error(strerror(errno));
    }
    ~GzWrite() {
        gzclose(gz_);
    }
    int write(const char* data, size_t len) {
        return gzwrite(gz_, data, len);
    }
    GzWrite(const GzWrite&) = delete; // keine Kopie
    GzWrite& operator=(const GzWrite&) = delete; // keine Zuweisung
};

void packe(const string& infn) {
    vector<char> indata = lese(infn); // lese Eingabe
    GzWrite gz{infn+".gz"}; // initialisiere Ausgabe
    auto res = gz.write(indata.data(), indata.size());
    if(res==0) throw std::runtime_error("Fehler beim Schreiben");
}
```